# Application keep old sql connection when switch database (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, load-balancing, haproxy

I have two SQL Server databases, server name are `sql1` and `sql2`.

When I switch database from `sql1` to `sql2` (using HaProxy), my application still keeps the old SQL connection to server `sql1`.

However, other applications (using Linq-to-SQL) can get the new SQL connection to `sql2`.

Please see my code below that's I using to get connection to SQL Server:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlserver"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        //do something...

        conn.Close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

What's my problem? How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you "switching" connections?

Comment: @Xedni: I using Haproxy to choose what is server my application connection. Maybe my question not clearly enough, I have not permission to access into Haproxy setting.

Comment: Your Haproxy is not working as you expecting, why don't you debug your code, you'll get hints where the problem is.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalidL:  I have not permission to access into Haproxy setting, I have requested and waiting IT admin help me to build Haproxy in Local then I can try to debugging. Until they are done I want to research solution to fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the HAProxy listen configuration, maybe your HAProxy has exceptions programmed, or the redirection only works if you use an specific IP address destination or come from an specific IP range. Please compare the connections string used in each case.

https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/11/load-balancing-microsoft-sql-server-with-haproxy/